# egrep regex not working on regex that works in other program

Tags: regex, grep

I have this working regex (tested on regex coach):

```
\n[\s]*[0-9]*[\s]*[0-9]*(\.)?[0-9]*(e\+)?[0-9]*
```

that is supposed to pick up the first 2 columns of this file

http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/highly.txt

I read through the man pages, and it says that ^ will match at the beggining of the line so I replaced \n with ^
but egrep isn't agreeing with me when I do this:

```
egrep -e ^[\s]*[0-9]*[\s]*[0-9]*(\.)?[0-9]*(e\+)?[0-9]* "wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de achim highly.txt"
```

EDIT: it has something to do with `(e\+)?`

EDIT 2: okay, I'm simplifying the regex. forget about trying to get numbers in scientific notation here is what I am using:

```
egrep -e "^[[:space:]]*[0-9]*[[:space:]]*[0-9]*" "wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de achim highly.txt"
```

it returns the header lines:

```
   no       number      divisors    2 3 5 71113171923293137414347535961677173
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this isn't right...

Final edit:

I needed a combination of grep and sed to get the proper data out.
grep removed the header lines and sed formatted the text

```
grep  -E -o -e "^[[:space:]]+[0-9]+[[:space:]]+[0-9e\+\.]+[[:space:]]+[0-9e\+\.]+" "wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de achim highly.txt" >grepped.txt

sed -r "s/^\s*[0-9]+\s*([0-9.e+]+)\s*([0-9.e+]+)/\1,\2/" "grepped.txt" >seded.txt
```

Comment: In what particular way is it "not agreeing"

Comment: You need to put your regex in quotes.  The characters `[]()*?\` all have special meaning to the shell.

Comment: @justintime: I added an edit 2: it's matching lines it shouldn't be matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERE does not support `\s`. Use `[[:space:]]` for `\s`, or simply  .

<del>It seems the `^` points to the start of *text that is not yet matched*. I don't know why.</del> (This behavior is true on grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1 on Mac OS X only?)

The regex matches the header lines because all elements in the regex is optional. You need to change some of those `*` into `+`.

---

Since the file is in fixed-length format, it is far easier to use `cut` than constructing a regex.

```
cut -c 1-20 highly.txt
```

You could use `grep -v` to filter out the undesired results.

Comment: Noted, problem still here. How do I force it to match the beginning of line only? It seems like egrep doesn't care that I added ^

Comment: Noted, but this doesn't get rid of the re-occurring headers

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `-o` option to grep to make it print only the part that matched the pattern instead of the line that has the pattern:

```
egrep -o -e  "^[[:space:]]*[0-9]*[[:space:]]*[0-9.e+]*" file
      ^^
```

[**Working link**](http://www.ideone.com/amtBz)

Alternatively you can use sed as:

```
sed -r 's/^\s*([0-9]+)\s*([0-9.e+]+).*/\1 \2/' file
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what tool I could use to do something like "^[[:space:]]*([0-9]*)[[:space:]]*([0-9.e+]*)" -output "\1,\2" ? I'm new to the whole bash :S

Answer (score 0):

if you have data that looks properly formatted, with delimiters that you can identify (eg in your case, tabs/spaces), there is no need to use regex. Use awk.

```
awk '!/--/&&$1!="no"{print $1,$2}' file
```

I believe this one liner is all you need since you said you want to get the first 2 columns and skip the headers. you can use `cut` too, but its not as flexible as awk.

Comment: how do I suppress the 'no-number' lines awk returns?